# Lebesgue integral of a sequence of floor functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,1) \rightarrow [0,1)$ be the identity function $f(x)=x$ for $x \in [0,1)$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n:[0,1) \rightarrow [0,1)$ by $f_n(x)=\lfloor2^nx\rfloor/2^n$ ; in other words, for $x \in [0,1)$ take the unique integer $i \in $ {$1,2,3,...,2^n$}$ $ such that $x \in [\frac{i-1}{2^n},\frac{i}{2^n})$ and define $f_n(x)=\frac{i-1}{2^n}.$

***Find the Lebesgue integral*** $\int_0^1f_n(x)dx$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am having difficulty showing this as I cannot assume if a function is Riemann integrable, then it is Lebesgue integrable and the integrals coincide. Otherwise I would just integrate it as usual.

How can this be computed with the assumption above?

Comment: You have a step function. The integral is the sum of the length of the intervals times the value on each interval

Comment: The Lebesgue integral is typically constructed using step functions - if you can use this definition, the calculation is very straightforward and intuitive without justification. However, since you're asking, it seems you have another construction, possibly the original one through the measure of preimages?! What are you allowed to use? At any rate, in the end the calculation will be "as usual".